# Case When with union between cases

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a SQL statement that looks like this:

```
select supplier, case when platform in (5,6) then 'mobile' 
               when platform in (7,8) then 'tablet' end as platform,
       count(*) as clicks
from supplier_table
group by supplier, platform;
```

This gives me the breakdown of clicks received by each supplier by different platforms
example : [("ABC",mobile, 200),("ABC", tablet, 300)] for supplier "ABC"

My aim is the do this plus find the sum of both the clicks and put it in a platform named lets say 'all'.

I tried doing that with the same SQL statement by adding an extra case.

```
select supplier, case when platform in (5,6) then 'mobile' 
        when platform in (7,8) then 'tablet' when platform in (5,6,7,8) then 'all' 
       end as platform,
       count(*) as clicks
from supplier_table
group by supplier, platform;
```

But this does not work and gives me the same result as above without the 'all' platform. Is it at possible at all by using Case When statement or do I need to do an upper level aggregation by selecting over the original SQL results?

Thanks.

Update:

It is MYsql (RDBMS) and yes I need a separate row with value 'all' (this would contain sum of clicks of both 'mobile' and 'tablet'.

eg: example : [("ABC",mobile, 200),("ABC", tablet, 300), ("ABC", all, 500)]

Comment: The criteria doesn't make sense... If a value is 5 or 6 then you have already chosen mobile. How could it possibly be all as well? Do you want this to be a new column can you please clarify?

Comment: Both your queries should crash because you don't have a group by clause.

Comment: Yeah I missed adding group by in the question. It is MYSQL and yes I need a separate row with value 'all' (this would contain sum of clicks of both 'mobile' and 'tablet'.

Comment: Despite saying "group by supplier, platform", "platform" is referring to the table's column, not your aliased field.  GROUP BY doesn't normally allow references to aliased fields - you have to repeat the logic you are aliasing in the group by as in my answer below.

Comment: Interesting that you mention `union` in our question, but haven't tried `UNION` in your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want results like

```
supplier platform clicks
abc      tablet   12
abc      mobile   34
```

Add your case statement to a GROUP BY

```
select supplier, case when platform in (5,6) then 'mobile' 
               when platform in (7,8) then 'tablet' end as platform,
       count(*) as clicks
from supplier_table
group by supplier,case when platform in (5,6) then 'mobile' 
               when platform in (7,8) then 'tablet' end
```

alternatively if you want results like this:

```
supplier tablet_clicks mobile_clicks total_clicks
abc      12            34            46
```

You could split your cases inside sums of 1 acting like a conditional count something like this:

```
select supplier, sum(case when platform in (5,6) then 1 end) as mobile_clicks,
               sum(case when platform in (7,8) then 1 end) as tablet_clicks,
               count(1) total_clicks
from supplier_table
group by supplier
```

And after seeing your update, If you want results like

```
supplier platform clicks total_clicks
abc      tablet   12     46
abc      mobile   34     46
```

You need to use a subquery like so

```
select supplier, case when platform in (5,6) then 'mobile' 
               when platform in (7,8) then 'tablet' end as platform,
       count(*) as clicks,
       (select count(1) from supplier_table as x where x.supplier=supplier_table.supplier where x.platform in (5,6,7,8)) as total_clicks
from supplier_table
group by supplier,case when platform in (5,6) then 'mobile' 
               when platform in (7,8) then 'tablet' end
```

If you want results like

```
supplier platform clicks
abc      tablet   12
abc      mobile   34
abc      all      46
```

you do use a UNION as suspected with a separate non-segregating query

```
select supplier, case when platform in (5,6) then 'mobile' 
               when platform in (7,8) then 'tablet' end as platform,
       count(*) as clicks
from supplier_table
group by supplier,case when platform in (5,6) then 'mobile' 
               when platform in (7,8) then 'tablet' end
UNION ALL
select supplier,'all',count(1) from supplier_table 
where platform in (5,6,7,8)
group by supplier
```

Comment: I think you still need to group by supplier in your second (UNION) query. Also, why not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Nice answer. Though, I would use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(1)` to be more legible. Optimizations that were gained with `COUNT(1)` are mostly obsolete.

Comment: You can also use the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier to `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your last `WHEN` criteria will never be met because one of the prior two will always be met first.  You need either a separate `CASE` statement, or perhaps a conditional `SUM()`, something like:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN platform in (5,6,7,8) THEN 1 END)
```

Also, you should have any non-aggregate values, including `CASE` statements in a `GROUP BY` clause, even if mySQL doesn't error out on incomplete `GROUP BY` clauses.